# Fetching data from Greenplum table in the order of 600 million in Apache NiFi is giving GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from Greenplum table using Apache NiFi - QueryDatabaseTableRecord. I am seeing GC overhead limit exceeded error and the NiFi webpage becomes unresponsive.

I have set the 'Fetch Size' property to 10000 but it seems the property is not being used in this case.

Other settings:

- Database Type : Generic
- Max Rows Per Flow File : 1000000
- Output Batch Size : 2
- jvm min/max memory allocation is 4g/8g

Is there an alternative to avoid the GC errors for this task ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a clear case of the "Fetch Size" parameter not being used, see processor info on this.
  Try to test the jdbc setFetchsize on its own to see if it works.